# cmdlet get-team runs in into throtteling

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams, office365api, throttling

I try to get a list all Teams from a Tennant.
There are about 100 Teams.
The cmdlet Get-Team runs for ages and the Powershell-log says

```
2020-12-04T14:38:27.8608271Z    Error       Get-Team.GetTeam                            Microsoft.TeamsCmdlets.PowerShell.Custom.ErrorHandling.ApiException - Error occurred while executing 
Code: TooManyRequests
Message: Too many requests from Identifier:XXXXXX under category:throttle.teams.ags.api_complex_level_10.app_normal.operation_read_sustained. Please try again later.
InnerError:
  RequestId: XXX
  DateTimeStamp: 2020-12-04T14:38:27
HttpStatusCode: TooManyRequests
.    bei Microsoft.TeamsCmdlets.PowerShell.Custom.Utils.HttpUtilities.Get[T](HttpClient httpClient, Uri requestUri, Dictionary`2 headers)
   bei Microsoft.TeamsCmdlets.PowerShell.Custom.TeamsCmdlet.GetTeam(String cmdletName, String uriSuffix, String groupId)
```

The API-Websites says, that the Get-Team call is limited to 60 requests/sec. I´m way below that value.
Even if I run it once, it takes several Minutes to complete. Is this a known bug? Does someone know a way around it?

*EDIT* I found a Solution: Install the latest prerelease (1.1.10) of the Teams-Module. With latest Stable (1.1.6) it didn´t work

Comment: As an FYI: we've seen issues today regarding `Get-Team` taking upto 5 minutes to return a single Team. This behaviour has been seen by others in my sector across the country (UK).

Answer (score 2):

what is the Version of module. if it is older version please update to latest.

Please check powershell version also.
if both are latest version. please run the get-team through [Graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) share the outcome.